# What is the difference between keras and keras-gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am setting up my computer to run DL with a GPU and I couldn't find info on whether one should install keras or keras-gpu. Currently I have it running with conda and keras using tensorflow-gpu as backend. What would be the difference if I switch keras to keras-gpu?

Comment: Are you talking of conda packages, right? You should clarify your question. I believe there is no particular gpu implementation for keras, so you'll have the same thing but in a single package.

Comment: Yes, I have now tested it with keras and keras-gpu in a small project and found no difference.

Comment: The difference is to run your code on cpu or gpu.

Comment: @MiloLu I thought that depends on what backend keras uses i.e. in my case tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu. For me it didn't do any difference if I use keras+tensorflow-gpu or keras-gpu+tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 2):

this is a paragraph borrowed from Wikipedia:
Keras was conceived to be an interface rather than a standalone machine-learning framework. It offers a higher-level, more intuitive set of abstractions that make it easy to develop deep learning models regardless of the computational backend used.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras 
So as long as all three back ends of Keras (TensorFlow, Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit, or Theano) do not support Gpu versions, using keras-gpu may cause you trouble.